# Force immediate evaluation of backreference during replace

Tags: powershell, replace

I am running into an error where I am concatenating strings together to obtain the field I want replaced.

Below is an example of what my script is doing:

```
$TEXTTOREPLACEWITH= '6Q'

(Get-Content testfile.html) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '(.*)\$\(STRINGTOREPLACE\)(.*)', ('$1' +$TEXTTOREPLACEWITH+'$2')
```

If I ran this against a file that had a line input as follows:

```
abc$(STRINGTOREPLACE)xyz
```

I expect the following output:

```
abc6Qxyz
```

INSTEAD, When I run this script the output looks as follows:

```
$16Qxyz
```

I'm assuming this is due to the fact that back-references must not be resolved until string concatenation is complete.  Is there any way in PowerShell to go ahead and resolve these back-references immediately and avoid the output that I am seeing?

Answer (score 3):

*1st, missing the point, answer replaced...*

When concatenate `'$1'` and `'6Q'` (before being passed to the regex engine) you get `$16Q` and there is no 16<sup>th</sup> capture to replace.

To avoid this, use named groups in the match (`(?<name>)`) and `${name}` in the replacement string.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx), and note:

> If *number* does not specify a valid capturing group defined in the regular expression pattern, `$number` is interpreted as a literal character sequence that is used to replace each match.

Comment: Those aren't variables though.  '$1' and '$2' are backreferences (captures from the regex match).  If I put them in double quotes it thinks I'm trying to resolve a PowerShell variable, which is not what I want to do.

Comment: Oops... you're right I've got the wrong end of the stick. 2nd A coming up :-)

Comment: Note that `${__}` works for both numbered and named references; i.e. `'${1}' + $TextToReplaceWith + '${2}'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using named capture groups:

```
$rx = '(?i)(?<Beg>.*)\$\(STRINGTOREPLACE\)(?<End>.*)'
$texttoreplacewith='${Beg}6Q${End}'
$x = "abc`$(stringtoreplace)xyz"

[regex]::Replace($x, $rx, $texttoreplacewith)
```